# How send image object through socket...?

Tags: java

I want to send image object through socket... Don't want to store image in sender or receivers computer...

Comment: Can you please elaborate `Don't want to store image in sender or receivers computer...`? If you send the data, both the sender and the receiver will have by definition access to it.

Answer (score 10):

Use this method:

```
  ImageIO.write(RenderedImage, String, OutputStream)
```

Use in your situation:

Sender

```
   BufferedImage image = ....;
   ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", socket.getOutputStream());
```

Receiver

```
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

So what have you tried ?

[This](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) is a tutorial on client/server communication using Java. This reads from stdin, but in your instance you should probably provide an [InputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) on your image object.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=32308) serialization for an image object to send it through the socket.