# Sending a screenshot (bufferedImage) over a socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedimage

I am sending a bufferedImage over a socket and I am using the example found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385649/how-send-image-object-through-socket) post:

Sender

```
   BufferedImage image = ....;
   ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", socket.getOutputStream());
```

Receiver

```
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
```

It works -  IF, and ONLY IF, I close the sender's outputStream after this line:

```
 ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", socket.getOutputStream());
```

Is there anything I can do apart from closing the outputStream?

Also, is there anything else I can do to avoid using ImageIO altogether? It seems to take ages to do anything. 
Also note that reading or writing to the hard disk in anyway should be avoided at all costs due to performance issues. I need to make this transfer as fast as possible, (I'm experimenting and trying to create a client similar to VNC and saving each screenshot to the hard disk would greatly slow down everything)..

@Jon Skeet

**Edit 3:**

*Sender:* (Note that I am sending a JPG image not a PNG).

```
                    int filesize;
                    OutputStream out = c.getClientSocket().getOutputStream();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bScrn = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIO.write(screenshot, "JPG", bScrn);
                    byte[] imgByte = bScrn.toByteArray();
                    bScrn.flush();
                    bScrn.close();

                    filesize = bScrn.size();
                    out.write(new String("#FS " + filesize).getBytes()); //Send filesize
                    out.write(new String("#<IM> \n").getBytes());        //Notify start of image

                    out.write(imgByte); //Write file
                    System.out.println("Finished");
```

*Reciever: (where `input` is the socket input stream)*

Attempt #1:

```
String str = input.toString();
imageBytes = str.getBytes();

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
in.close();

System.out.println("width=" + image.getWidth());
```

**(failed: Nullpointer exception on getWidth() line)**
I understand this error to mean "corrupt image" because it couldn't initialize it. correct?

Attempt #2:

```
byte[] imageBytes = new byte[filesize];
for (int j = 0; i < filesize; i++)
{
    imageBytes[j] = (byte) input.read();
}

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
in.close();

System.out.println("width=" + image.getWidth());
```

**(failed: Nullpointer exception on getWidth() line)**

Attempt #3:

```
if (filesize > 0)
{

    int writtenBytes = 0;
    int bufferSize = client.getReceiveBufferSize();

    imageBytes = new byte[filesize];     //Create a byte array as large as the image
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];//Create buffer


    do {
        writtenBytes += input.read(buffer); //Fill up buffer
        System.out.println(writtenBytes + "/" + filesize); //Show progress

        //Copy buffer to the byte array which will contain the full image
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, imageBytes, writtenBytes, client.getReceiveBufferSize());
        writtenBytes+=bufferSize;

    } while ((writtenBytes + bufferSize) < filesize);

    // Read the remaining bytes
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, imageBytes, writtenBytes-1, filesize-writtenBytes);
    writtenBytes += filesize-writtenBytes;
    System.out.println("Finished reading! Total read: " + writtenBytes + "/" + filesize);

}

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
in.close();
```

**(failed: Reciever gives: Null pointer exception)**

Attempt 4:

```
   int readBytes = 0;
   imageBytes = new byte[filesize];     //Create a byte array as large as the image



    while (readBytes < filesize)
    {
        readBytes += input.read(imageBytes);
    }

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
    in.close();

    System.out.println("width=" + image.getWidth());
```

**(failed: sender gives: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error)**

Attempt #5:

Using Jon skeet's code snippet, the image arrives, but only partially. I saved it to a file (1.jpg) to see what was going on, and it actually sends 80% of the image, while the rest of the file is filled with blank spaces.  This results in a partially corrupt image. Here is the code I tried: (note that captureImg() is not at fault, saving the file directly works)

Sender:

```
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1290);
    OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bScrn = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(captureImg(), "JPG", bScrn);
    byte imgBytes[] = bScrn.toByteArray();
    bScrn.close();

    out.write((Integer.toString(imgBytes.length)).getBytes());
    out.write(imgBytes,0,imgBytes.length);
```

Reciever:

```
    InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    byte[] b = new byte[30];
    int len = in.read(b);

    int filesize = Integer.parseInt(new String(b).substring(0, len));

    if (filesize > 0)
    {
        byte[] imgBytes = readExactly(in, filesize);
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Dan\\Desktop\\Pic\\1.jpg");
        f.write(imgBytes);
        f.close();

        System.out.println("done");
```

The sender still gives a  Connection reset by peer: socket write error.
[Click here for full sized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xsvW.png) [image: Problem]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to write the image to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` so you can determine the length, then write that length to the output stream first.

Then on the receiving end, you can read the length, then read that many bytes into a byte array, then create a `ByteArrayInputStream` to wrap the array and pass *that* to `ImageIO.read()`.

I'm not entirely surprised that it doesn't work until the output socket is closed normally - after all, a file which contains a valid PNG file *and then something else* isn't actually a valid PNG file in itself, is it? So the reader needs to read to the end of the stream before it can complete - and the "end" of a network stream only comes when the connection is closed.

EDIT: Here's a method to read the given number of bytes into a new byte array. It's handy to have as a separate "utility" method.

```
public static byte[] readExactly(InputStream input, int size) throws IOException
{
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    int index = 0;
    while (index < size)
    {
        int bytesRead = input.read(data, index, size - index);
        if (bytesRead < 0)
        {
            throw new IOException("Insufficient data in stream");
        }
        index += bytesRead;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: @David: That's very convoluted code - in particular, you should never be catching ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Why aren't you just using `out.write(imgByte)`? And on the receiving side you're using `client.getInputStream().read(buffer);` which is *completely ignoring* the return value of `read`. Not a good idea. Call `getInputStream()` *once*, and then call `read` multiple times, noting how much data has been read on each call. Don't assuming it will always be the same as the receive size.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention. out.write(imgByte) somehow instantly forces the socket to close, and disconnects the client. I can't understand why it's happening, but I thought there must be a limit to how much data you can write at one go, so I tried splitting and sending it.

Comment: @David: No, it should be absolutely fine to write out data to a socket. Are you sure it wasn't the *receiving* side which closed the socket?

Comment: @David: You're still ignoring the return value of `input.read()`. You *mustn't* do that. You need to loop around, working out how much data you still need to read, and reading a chunk at a time. Over a network connection, you *won't* get it all in one go.

Comment: Just did that - edited attempt 4. The reciever does not give any errors. The sender, however, just disconnects and says "Connection reset by peer" when I try to write over 200kb at one go to the output stream. Any ideas?

Comment: @David: Well, you're now *overwriting* the data each time - you need to read *from where you'd got to* into the rest of the buffer. I suspect you're actually managing to finish receiving all the data (hence you're closing the socket), but as you've overwritten the existing data on each read, you're then failing to decode the image.

Comment: And what do you suggest that I use to copy what I'd got from the buffer into imgByte? System.ArrayCopy? If that's the case, please look at Attempt #3 and tell me why it's failing.

Comment: @David: You can read straight into `imgByte`. I'll add a quick snippet of code... note that this is nothing to do with ImageIO really.

Comment: if you are interested take a look at what happened. If you're tired of this I can understand ;)

Comment: @David: Yes, that's exactly what I'd expect - you're only ever reading data into the start of the buffer, so most of your file is blank. Have you tried the snippet I provided?

Comment: That's using the snippet you provided. Notice the line  byte[] imgBytes = readExactly(in, filesize); Note that I'm referring to Attempt #5, reciever.

Comment: @David: I've now noticed how you're writing the length to the file. Don't do that! You're reading a random amount of data up to 30 bytes - there's no guarantee that what you read will be a valid string at all. Write it out using something like `DataOutputStream.writeInt` and read it with `DataInputStream.readInt`. You should check that you're transmitting the *size* correctly before you go any further...

Comment: I used to have a System.out.println(filesize) there but I removed it. It was valid in the first place. (Although I agree it's bad practice). I used writeInt now and I still have exactly the same problem. You can run it and see if you want.

Comment: @David: *Exactly* the same problem? Are the files the same size as each other now? Do they *start* with the same data? I can't really run the code easily without spending a fair amount of time setting everything else up. If you could edit your post to *just* a short but complete client/server pair using the latest code, I'll see if I can find time to diagnose it more thoroughly tonight.

Answer (score 2):

for other StackOverflow users like me.

In "Jon Skeet's" answer. Modify the following line of readExactly method.

```
    <<original Line>>
    index += size;
    <<modified Line>>
    index += bytesRead;
```

To get the full image data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        DataInputStream dis;
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.48",8000);
        while (true) {
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            int len = dis.readInt();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            dis.readFully(buffer, 0, len);
            BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
            jlb.setIcon(new ImageIcon(im));
            jfr.add(jlb);
            jfr.pack();
            jfr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jfr.setVisible(true);
            System.gc();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In 192.168.1.48:8000 machine python server running and i got stream in java code