# Transforming of images in Java. Transferring of images through sockets

Tags: java, image, sockets

I have a laptop and Microcontroller Evaluation Board MCB1700 with microcontroller NXP1768.
MCB1700 has Ethernet port, LCD (320 x 240) etc. I have IDE µVision V4.03q for developing and downloading C-programs on MCB1700. Also I have ULINK-pro device for downloading C-programs on MCB1700.

My task is:

1. to implement Java- client for laptop that reads image from laptop, converts this image to RGB16 (LCD of MCB1700 supports such image representation) and sends it to MCB1700 through socket connection
2. to implement server on MCB1700 that receives images from laptop through Socket-connection and displays it on LCD.
3. Actually there is a lot of other tasks to do and laptop must also send to MCB1700 the name of command to perform. But the question is about connection between laptop and MCB1700.

I have almost done the server side. My current version of server creates Passive socket connection and waits for client. It also can send and receive data through Ethernet.
My Java-client connects to the server successfully. I tested it by sending and receiving of short lines. Now I can develop it for sending to the server the Command’s name (for example “SHOW ON LCD:”) and RGB16-image.

The question is:
What is the best way to send the name of Command and RGB16-image from Java-client to MCB1700-server (implemented on C) through socket-connection for convenient casting of data in server C-program? It would be great to send all data in form of byte-array:

MCB1700-server must recieve data in form of bytes sequence

```
char* "SHOW ON LCD:" - bytes 0 - 11
unsigned short**
RGB16-Pixel[0][0] = 09 AE - bytes 12 - 13
RGB16-Pixel[0][1] =  14 1C    -   bytes 14 - 15
RGB16-Pixel[319][239] =  78 9F     -   bytes 76810 - 76811
```

(Sorry for quality of this illustration)

What is the best way to read an image of any format in Java-client and send it to MCB1700 in form of bytes- array (like on picture above)? What functions, classes should I use?
Actually, I have some ideas:

1)  I can put image in some way (I don’t know yet how) in Object of type  `BufferedImage`  (it supports needed format of image):

```
BufferedImage image =
    new BufferedImage(320, 240, TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
```

2)  Read every pixel of it in loop.

```
int oldRGB = image.getRGB(250, 180);
```

3)  And send each pixel of image sequentially byte after byte

```
Socket connectionToDevice;  //Socket
 OutputStream outToServerStream;
 outToServerStream = connectionToDevice.getOutputStream();
 outToServerStream.write(    bytes of pixel to send   );
```

Is there a more graceful way to perform this task? 
How should I read and transform image in Java-client?

4)  I have found such interesting way of image-transmission through socket using of such `ImageIO` method:
[Sending a screenshot (bufferedImage) over a socket in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973848/sending-a-screenshot-bufferedimage-over-a-socket-in-java)

```
public static boolean write(RenderedImage im,
                            String formatName,
                            OutputStream output)


BufferedImage image = ....;
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", socket.getOutputStream());
```

But I am not sure that it is suitable in my case. How does    `String formatName`  influence on stream? I haven’t any idea. May be it adds some extra bytes...

Comment: By my count you have 6 questions there.  Would you like a 1/6 of an answer to each one, or should I pick one at random to answer?  Or to put that another way, try to limit it to one question per post - I reckon it will take a very bored person to answer all 6 questions (or even read all that).

Comment: Sorry I am novice on this resource. I didn't see you comment yesterday. I would like to know answer on the last question. It is much important for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", socket.getOutputStream());
```

> How does `String formatName` influence on stream?

It informs the method as to what what format to encode the image.  For the supported formats, see [`ImageIO.getWriterFileSuffixes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getWriterFileSuffixes%28%29).

In coding terms it simply boils down to:

1. Use a known, supported format.
2. Use the same format at the sender as the receiver.

PNG is a good choice.  It is not lossy like JPEG, nor limited to 256 colors like GIF.  For those reasons it is the *only* recommended format for [posting screenshots at stack exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I don't need any format ("PNG","JPEG", etc.). Microcontroller doesn't support them. I want to send an image like a sequence of RGB565-pixels (for example:            12_1F 24_C3 ... 67_02 ). Server (implemented on C-language) receives it, sets (unsigned short *) pointer on data-field and we have acceses to pixel [0][0] (12_1F) of image-matrix through this pointer. After operation pointer++ we have access to the next pixel [0][1] (24_C3) and so on... Is it posible with ImageIO.write(...) or in other way?