# Sending an image over a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am lately trying to create a program, just like teamviewer. It's going kinda well, but I am currently facing a problem.

I am trying to make my program send an image over the socket. When I run this code, it never outputs "Image should be sent!", so I think the problem is in the ImageIO.write line.

```
BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
try {
    ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Image should be sent!");
} catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if ( socket != null ){
        try { socket.close(); } catch (IOException ex){}
    }
    System.out.println("Image sent and socket closed!");
}
```

There is also a client on the other side, consuming the data being sent by the code above.
The code to do this is:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
f.getContentPane().add(label);
```

Now my question is, what is wrong with this code, and how can I make this work?

Comment: Not an answer: Why don't you just use VNC? It's basically a Teamviewer with no NAT traversal (so you have to modify it there if you want your own TW.) But that's it. UltraVNC, TightVNC and there are many others.

Comment: @Shiki well, I just want to add other features that other programs don't have. Some programs may have a few of the features I could think of, but none has all.

Comment: I notice you don't write the length of the image to the socket (perhaps you don't need it); Second, I would suggest wrapping the `socket.getOutputStream()` with a `BufferedOutputStream`. Finally, I would close the OutputStream (and flush before) I closed the socket.

Comment: You mean the program "hangs" on the line with `ImageIO.write`, right? Is there a client that is consuming the data on the other end of the socker?

Comment: @rzymek True, it hangs at that line. And yes, there is a client consuming the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending a screenshot (bufferedImage) over a socket in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973848/sending-a-screenshot-bufferedimage-over-a-socket-in-java)

Comment: @user2988879: That's why I said that you could just beef up some existing code instead of making everything from scratch. But it's not a problem, of course not. You are free to do anything you want, just an idea/tip/whatever. A comment. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the code looks ok. Here's a complete code, that works fine on my machine:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    try (ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(25000)) {
      System.out.println("waiting...");
      try (Socket socket = serv.accept()) {
        System.out.println("client connected");
        ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("sent");
      }
    }
  }
}

class Client {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try(Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 25000)){
      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
      JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
      JFrame f = new JFrame("vnc");
      f.getContentPane().add(label);
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Though this will only work if you close the socket after sending the images. It will fail if you'll just try to send a few images over the same socket. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6973863/211205.

Comment: Thanks dude, this worked perfectly for me. Had to change a few little things, but now everything works just as I would like it to.

Comment: what would be a way not to have to close the socket? perhaps send a 'EOF' text?

Answer (score 1):

I had worked on this earlier and posted the solution in my blog. Please visit it for complete source code. Need your feed back too.

You need to read thread, socket and image writing to do this.

http://javabelazy.blogspot.in/2013/10/sending-screenshot-from-client-to.html

```
BufferedImage screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(dimensions));
ImageIO.write(screenshot,"png",serverSocket.getOutputStream());
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(fileName+".png"))
```